# How use AngularJS directives in reactJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I have a working project on AngularJS and I have a problem rendering. I need to render many elements (1000+) in one page and very fast. To solve this problem, I decided to use ReactJS. But... I have these elements

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users>
  <td><span data-my-directive="user.data"></span></td>
</tr>
```

How can I render this on ReactJS. How can I run my angular directive? I have many Angular directives, how can I make angular friends with ReactJS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Angular Directives from inside React.

You can call React.RenderComponent from within your angular directive.  A detailed example is presented [here](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/).

However, the style of code in the example would quickly lead to a mess of a frankenstine application framework.  If your angular application is mostly in Angular, I would suggest wrapping your react functionality inside it's own module and exposing the required features from services to keep things at least somewhat compartmentalised.